# Rotate picturebox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rotation, picturebox

How do I rotate a picturebox using code? I know I can use rotateflip, but that only rotates it 90, 180 or 270 degrees. Is there a way to rotate the image, say 30 degrees, without having to rotate the image outside of VB and importing the rotated version?

Comment: What platform? WFP and Silverlight are up to that.

Answer (score 0):

This page [How to: Rotate, Reflect, and Skew Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) should give you a step in the right direction.